# Finding index of needle in haystack recursively.

Tags: c++

I am pretty close to completing my function. I need to take 2 strings, and return the index of string 2 inside of string 1. I know there is a find function for this, but I am not able to use it. It also has to be done with recursive programming.

I have the following.

```
int index_of(string haystack, string needle) {

    int index = 0;
    string test = haystack.substr(index, needle.length());

    if (test == needle) {
        return index;
    }
    else {
        return 1 + index_of(haystack.substr(1), needle);
    }

}
```

It returns the index of the needle in the haystack no problem but there are 2 things it needs to do I can not figure out.

1) If the needle is not in the haystack, then it needs to return a -1. I have done it so at the end if it does not exist, it returns a -1, but because it is recursive, it then adds the other times it returned 1. I am not sure how to just return a single value at the end without adding all the other instances on it.

2) I am suppose to use a helper function within it and I am not sure how to do that either.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you want to return the value of a recursive function unadulterated. In your case, this:

`return 1 + index_of(some_parameters);`

Should be this:

`return index_of(some_parameters);`

Now, you just need to choose parameters such that you can keep track of the index until you need to return it, or alternatively -1.

One such function might have the constructor:

```
index_of(string haystack, string needle, int index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be implemented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string::size_type index_of( std::string haystack, const std::string &needle ) 
{
    if ( haystack.size() < needle.size() ) return std::string::npos;

    if ( haystack.compare( 0, needle.size(), needle ) == 0 ) return 0;

    std::string::size_type index;

    return ( index = index_of( haystack.substr( 1 ), needle ) ) == std::string::npos ? index : ++index; 
}

int main()
{
    std::string haystack( "asdfghjkl" );
    std::string needle( "gh" );

    std::string::size_type index = index_of( haystack, needle );

    if ( index != std::string::npos )
    {
        std::cout << "string \"" << needle 
                  << "\" is found in string \"" << haystack 
                  << "\" at position " << index
                  << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "string \"" << needle 
                  << "\" is not found in string \"" << haystack << "\""
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Its output is

```
string "gh" is found in string "asdfghjkl" at position 4
```

Of course the simplest approach is to define a static variable that would keep the current position in the source string. But in this case I do not think that such a function is a "pure recursive".